# How do I install the Field Redirection module?

Tags: redirection

How do I install the [Field Redirection](https://drupal.org/project/field_redirection) module?

I want to display a photo on the front page that redirects to another page. I have [Md Foto](http://demo.megadrupal.com/d7/md-foto/) theme and would like the photos on the front page to click through to a basic text content, a different node.

Comment: did you read the documentation? does it not explain how to set it up?